# Using ctypes for a message box in Python

Tags: python, popup

I'm trying to make a simple message box in Python and have the following:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, "Text", "Title", 0)
```

and it works perfect in Pycharm.  But when I put it in a Jupyter notebook I get an error that ctypes doesn't have a windll attribute.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Is it an online notebook?

Comment: Yes, it works in PyCharm but not the online notebook

Comment: You could `import platform; print(platform.platform())` to see what OS is running online. If its not Windows, there is no windll. But what use would there be inopening a message box on some anonymous server somewhere? Likely there isn't a display surface for it.

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```py
import ctypes # An included library with Python install.  
def message(title, message, style):
    ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxW(0, message, title, style)
```

Comment: and use python 3.11 and thonny because it works for me that way

Comment: How is this related to OP’s question? They said they’re getting a `windll` error. Your code is basically the same.

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**